# How to access a sibling directive Object (not DOMNode)

Tags: angular

Given following HTML template:

```html
<input my-directive-a="foo" my-directive-b="bar"/>
```

Is there a way to detect within `my-directive-a` that on the same *Host*, `my-directive-b` is also present? Furthermore, how would I get access to that object?

Ideally, I would use some analogue to `@ViewChild`:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[my-directive-a]'
})
export class DirectiveA {

   @ViewChild(DirectiveB) myDirectiveB: DirectiveB;
}
```

But this does only work in the host *component*.

I know that where are other answers that deal with the communication of two directives (e.g. through `@Input` or a *shared service*), but I don't want to force the users of `my-directive-a` to always declare `my-directive-b` as well. I already have a working solution for instantiating `my-directive-b` *if not present*, but since where are legitimate use cases for both directives to be declared independently of each other on the same host element, I wanted to optimize my solution to reuse `my-directive-b` instead of creating another instance of it.

Answer (score 4):

Directives are injected into the component, which means that you will have absolutely no issue injecting them into each other.

See [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5cefvs)

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appA]'
})
export class ADirective {

  constructor(
    private B: BDirective
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.B.some);
  }

}
```